# Laravel and images display

Tags: php, laravel, png, jpeg

I'm using laravel 5.2, in this moment I'm testing my views with the builtin php server. To display images in the views, I used this code

`<img src="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" alt="logo">`

when I load the page with a browse I don't see the images, if I try inspect the code I see

`<img src="http://localhost:8010/images/logo.png" alt="logo">`

Then, if I try to follow the link of the image, I don't see the image but it's code:

http://p4c.it/test.jpg

it's clear that I'm doing something wrong, is this issue related with the definition of mime types? For what I see the `{{asset('my_file_here')}}` works fine with css files and jvascript.

Comment: path will be `http://localhost:8010/laravel_dir_name/images/logo.png`?

Comment: if it is in assests folder<img src="{{asset('assests/images/logo.png')}}" alt="logo">

Comment: well I don't think that it's related with the directories structure, because the builtin php server  `php artisan serve --port=8010` gives me these logs when I open a view http://p4c.it/log.txt ... no 404 errors ... I've only 200 errors and images are in the public directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first create virtual host and check your image folder permission .

Comment: I double checked `chown -R www-data:www-data ./public && chmod -R 644 ./public`

Answer (score 0):

The resources folder is used for your blade views, localisation and uncompiled css/js files (SASS, LESS etc) (as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/structure#the-root-directory) in the Laravel docs). Instead put your pictures in a sub-folder within the `public` folder. The `public` folder should have sufficient permissions by default and then it should work. Make sure to double check those permissions (should be 775, 755 or 777, depending on your preferences).

--

I recommend you use [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) which allows you to easily create HTML with *blade* syntax. It seems they do not display all of what you can do with this package, but you will eventually be able to do the following:

```
{!! Html::image('images/logo.png') !!}
```

You can also use this to pass along an `alt` or classes for example:

```
{!! Html::image('images/logo.png', 'your alt', ['class' => 'your classes here']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with permissions and with the built-in php server, infact I set a site-available conf file in my nginx server and everything worked.